# In PHP, how to keep style attributes for img tag

Tags: regex, preg-replace

this is my code:

```
$pattern = '!<(img\s[^>]*?)>!is';
$html = '<img height="401" width="830" style="width:200px;height:150px" class="media-element file-default" typeof="Image" src="http://localhost.com/sites/default/files/sample_chart.png" alt="">';
$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'custom_callback', $html);
```

In this code, how to keep style attribute of img tag

Where style attributes comes at any where withing img tag. I want to keep it.

Comment: Use a DOM parser for this task, you will have less headache.

Comment: I need to do this using preg_replace_callback()

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more than that. You might get some answers that will "help" you get a bit further, but you will keep on having troubles with regex HTML manipulations like that one. It is time you changed the approach here.

Comment: Can you please provide your output which you want?

Comment: @Guru Did you find a solution to your problem? Was my answer useful? Do you need more help or explanation? I spent 1 hour to write solution for you last Friday, some feedback would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

**Regex 1**: `preg_replace("/(<img\s?)(.*)(style=\".*?\")(.*)(>)/i", "$1$2$3", $imageTag)`

or

**Regex 2**: `preg_replace("/<img.*(style=\".*?\").*>/i", "<img $1>", $imageTag)`?

**Note**: I didn't benchmark, but it is probably more efficient to use a single capture group (the second regex).

**In your example**:`<img height="401" width="830" style="width:200px;height:150px" class="media-element file-default" typeof="Image" src="http://localhost.com/sites/default/files/sample_chart.png" alt="">`

**Both regex returns**: `<img style="width:200px;height:150px">`

1. Group 1: `<img`
2. Not captured: `height="401" width="830"`
3. Group 2: `style="width:200px;height:150px"` (unique group in the second regex)
4. Not captured:`class="media-element file-default" typeof="Image" src="http://localhost.com/sites/default/files/sample_chart.png" alt=""`
5. Group 3: `>`

**Explanation regex 1**:

1. `(<img\s?)`: The parenthesis are for the capture group. Match the literal text `<img` and an optional (the question mark means 0 or 1 time) space`\s`.
2. `.*`: Match any character (the dot) 0 or more time (the star).
3. `(style=\".*?\")`: The parenthesis are for the capture group. Match the literal text `style=\"`. You need to escape the quote since you will use the regex in a string in PHP. Match any character (the dot) 0 or more time (the star) as few time as possible (the question mark after a quantifier). Since the star (*) is followed by a question mark (?), it will stop catching character as soon as it reach the first quote `\"`.
4. `.*`: Match any character (the dot) 0 or more time (the star).
5. `(>)`: Capture group for the closing

**Replacement**: `$1$2$3` replace the text by the capturing group 1, 2 and 3 and ignore the rest

**Explanation regex 2**:

1. `<img.*`: Match the literal text `<img` and an optional (the question mark means 0 or 1 time) space`\s` followed by any character (the star) 0 or many time (the star).

2.`(style=\".*?\")`: The parenthesis are for the capture group. Match the literal text `style=\"`. You need to escape the quote since you will use the regex in a string in PHP. Match any character (the dot) 0 or more time (the star) as few time as possible (the question mark after a quantifier). Since the star (*) is followed by a question mark (?), it will stop catching character as soon as it reach the first quote `\"`.

3. `.*>`: Match any character (the dot) as many time as you can (the star) until you reach the end of the tag (>).

**Replacement**: `<img $1>` replace the text by the literal `<img` followed by a space the single capturing and the closing symbol of the tag.

**Tested with**: https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Good success